# What is the Purpose of the Coliseum?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

What is the Coliseum for? I only have the option to fight against Omega as I had the Amazon pre-order. Is it planned to be used only for other DLC battles, or does it integrate into the story somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two versions of the Coliseum: one to the far left of the Historia Crux and one that appears in line with the main story gates.

#### Far left Coliseum

This is used for DLC. Periodically, Square-Enix releases an opponent you can face in the Coliseum which allows you to collect their monster crystal. Currently, you can face the following opponents:

- Omega
- Lightning & Amodar
- Nabaat
- Ultros & Typhon
- Gilgamesh
- PuPu
- Snow
- Valfodr

#### Main story Coliseum

You take a short detour here to collect a fragment as part of the events that occur in Episode 3, Part II. While there, you can collect a number of treasure spheres.

Comment: And it holds a fragment.

Comment: @user1016253 Ah yes, you're right: added.