# How can I get outfits?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

After playing FFXIII-2 for a few hours, I still haven't gotten any outfits. I noticed that one's for sale in the PlayStation Store, but I haven't gotten any through gameplay. Can you get any without spending more money? How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apart from the [preorder bonuses](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/49587/3389) or the purchase of the Nordic edition of the game, there is currently only one free outfit: the [Style and Steel](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_XIII-2_Downloadable_Content#cite_ref-30) outfit for Serah. It can be downloaded from the PSN Store or Xbox Live just like any other DLC and from the game (*DLC* on main menu).

Outside of that, outfits—like [the Coliseum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/49758/3389)—are purely for paid DLC.

Answer (score 1):

The current outfits for sale are:

Serah
Summoner's Garb (Part of the Omega DLC/Pre Order bonus),
Beachwear, 
N7 Amour,
Style And Steel and
White Mage Attire

Noel
Battle Attire (Part of the Omega DLC/Pre Order Bonus),
SpaceTime Guardian,
N7 Armour,
Ezio Auditore and 
Black Mage Attire

(accurate as of 18th May, subject to edits in future)

Comment: There's Final Fantasy/Mass Effect crossover DLC?  That's weird!

Answer (score -3):

Anything you can't do is DLC-only; this includes outfits :P